# Spline Interpolation Algorithm in GPUImage framework

Tags: algorithm, interpolation, gpuimage, spline, derivative

I used **GPUImage** framework (**GPUImageToneCurveFilter**) to read Adobe acv file and generate the LUT for shader texture recently. After successfully using this utility to render customized color tone in my image, I'm curious what kind of spline interpolation algorithm was used to achieve that. In the sample code, I could find out there're some second derivative calculation. But I can't understand where the math parameters came from. Is it possible to tell me some theoretical reference for further interpolation studying? Thanks.

**[Edit]**

As Spektre mentioned below, I paste the codes of spline calculation in **GPUImageToneCurveFilter.m**. It was **Objective-C** version.

After getting control points from ACV file and convert them from (0, 1) to (0, 255), send the points to splineCurve function for interpolation as below:

```
NSMutableArray *splinePoints = [self splineCurve:convertedPoints];
```

Two interpolating functions as:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)splineCurve:(NSArray *)points
{
    NSMutableArray *sdA = [self secondDerivative:points];

    // [points count] is equal to [sdA count]
    NSInteger n = [sdA count];
    if (n < 1)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    double sd[n];

    // From NSMutableArray to sd[n];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    {
        sd[i] = [[sdA objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
    }


    NSMutableArray *output = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:(n+1)];

    for(int i=0; i<n-1 ; i++) 
    {
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR || TARGET_OS_IPHONE
        CGPoint cur = [[points objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
        CGPoint next = [[points objectAtIndex:(i+1)] CGPointValue];
#else
        NSPoint cur = [[points objectAtIndex:i] pointValue];
        NSPoint next = [[points objectAtIndex:(i+1)] pointValue];
#endif

        for(int x=cur.x;x<(int)next.x;x++) 
        {
            double t = (double)(x-cur.x)/(next.x-cur.x);

            double a = 1-t;
            double b = t;
            double h = next.x-cur.x;

            double y= a*cur.y + b*next.y + (h*h/6)*( (a*a*a-a)*sd[i]+ (b*b*b-b)*sd[i+1] );

            if (y > 255.0)
            {
                y = 255.0;   
            }
            else if (y < 0.0)
            {
                y = 0.0;   
            }
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR || TARGET_OS_IPHONE
            [output addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)]];
#else
            [output addObject:[NSValue valueWithPoint:NSMakePoint(x, y)]];
#endif
        }
    }

    // The above always misses the last point because the last point is the last next, so we approach but don't equal it.
    [output addObject:[points lastObject]];
    return output;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)secondDerivative:(NSArray *)points
{
    const NSInteger n = [points count];
    if ((n <= 0) || (n == 1))
    {
        return nil;
    }

    double matrix[n][3];
    double result[n];
    matrix[0][1]=1;
    // What about matrix[0][1] and matrix[0][0]? Assuming 0 for now (Brad L.)
    matrix[0][0]=0;    
    matrix[0][2]=0;    

    for(int i=1;i<n-1;i++) 
    {
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR || TARGET_OS_IPHONE
        CGPoint P1 = [[points objectAtIndex:(i-1)] CGPointValue];
        CGPoint P2 = [[points objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
        CGPoint P3 = [[points objectAtIndex:(i+1)] CGPointValue];
#else
        NSPoint P1 = [[points objectAtIndex:(i-1)] pointValue];
        NSPoint P2 = [[points objectAtIndex:i] pointValue];
        NSPoint P3 = [[points objectAtIndex:(i+1)] pointValue];
#endif

        matrix[i][0]=(double)(P2.x-P1.x)/6;
        matrix[i][1]=(double)(P3.x-P1.x)/3;
        matrix[i][2]=(double)(P3.x-P2.x)/6;
        result[i]=(double)(P3.y-P2.y)/(P3.x-P2.x) - (double)(P2.y-P1.y)/(P2.x-P1.x);
    }

    // What about result[0] and result[n-1]? Assuming 0 for now (Brad L.)
    result[0] = 0;
    result[n-1] = 0;

    matrix[n-1][1]=1;
    // What about matrix[n-1][0] and matrix[n-1][2]? For now, assuming they are 0 (Brad L.)
    matrix[n-1][0]=0;
    matrix[n-1][2]=0;

    // solving pass1 (up->down)
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++) 
    {
        double k = matrix[i][0]/matrix[i-1][1];
        matrix[i][1] -= k*matrix[i-1][2];
        matrix[i][0] = 0;
        result[i] -= k*result[i-1];
    }
    // solving pass2 (down->up)
    for(NSInteger i=n-2;i>=0;i--)
    {
        double k = matrix[i][2]/matrix[i+1][1];
        matrix[i][1] -= k*matrix[i+1][0];
        matrix[i][2] = 0;
        result[i] -= k*result[i+1];
    }

    double y2[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) y2[i]=result[i]/matrix[i][1];

    NSMutableArray *output = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:n];
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) 
    {
        [output addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:y2[i]]];
    }

    return output;
}
```

Hope these explanations could help to figure out what kind of algorithm that Brad L. used to interpolate the curve that makes the result as Photoshop did.

Comment: at least share the links you are describing ... we do not know the methods you are writing about so we can not help without specifics ...

Comment: @Spektre, thank you. I appended some information in the end of my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do nor recognize the language (apart the **C++** like stuff) so it is hard to read it (for me) but I think this

```
double y= a*cur.y + b*next.y + (h*h/6)*( (a*a*a-a)*sd[i]+ (b*b*b-b)*sd[i+1] );
```

is what you are asking about. The term:

```
a*cur.y + b*next.y
```

is basic linear interpolation so when `t=0.0` the result is current point and if `t=1.0` the result is next point. The rest is some kind of superponated curve with specific parameters probably producing some kind of bump pattern for the gradient scaled by the distance of points (that is why deltas are used for it). To reverse it would be hard (and I am too lazy for that) but the therms are reminding me of **Bernstein polynomials** (Used for **BEZIER** and **SPLINE**). The `a^3` and `b^3` suggest cubic curve. You should start with plotting graph which it produce and than try to create a polynomial interpolation that will have similar properties. If the result match the term you found you answer. For more info see this:

- [How can i produce multi point linear interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30438865/2521214)

And all the links there (especially the `How to construct own interpolation` ones).

Comment: These terms and explanations are exactly what I need to start to study in this field. I read other articles in the link you provided, not only for the further mathematic discussion and also learned a lot about the curve and point rendering in your other articles (ex. using GDI, VCL, OpenGL etc.). Thank you.

Comment: @CasperChang glad to be of help. Once you done with interpolation and move to using it for graphics or whatever take a look at this [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) they are usually used to place objects/curves in the 3D space and for bidirectional coordinate transformations which is essential for 3D graphics. You can expand all this to any number of dimensions like [4D rendering techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44970550/2521214) and [4D rotations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45116079/2521214)