# Programmatically Finding the Faces of a Cube/Tesseract

Tags: algorithm, 3d, geometry, 4d

I am working on a cube/tesseract visualization project and I need help with programmatically finding the faces/sides of a cube/tesseract.

For both n=3 and n=4 I would like a face to be 4 connected vertices, for example:

```
face[0] = [0, 1, 3, 2]
```

6 of them for n=3 and 48 for n=4.

Is there an algorithm for finding the faces of an n-dimensional cube?

The vertices are generated by the following code:

```js
function generateVertices() {
  const numDimensions = parseInt(document.getElementById('numDimensions').value);
  const numVertices = Math.pow(2, numDimensions);
  const vertices = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
    const vertex = [];

    for (let j = 0; j < numDimensions; j++) {
      const coord = (i & (1 << j)) === 0 ? 1 : -1;
      vertex.push(coord);
    }

    vertices.push(vertex);
  }

  console.clear();

  console.log(`Number of vertices: ${vertices.length}`);

  for (let i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
    console.log(`[${vertices[i].join(', ')}]`);
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="numDimensions">Number of dimensions:</label>
<input type="number" id="numDimensions" value="3">
<button onclick="generateVertices()">Generate Vertices</button>
```

Comment: *"Is there an algorithm for finding the faces of an n-dimensional cube?"* Yes, maybe? What do you know about this cube?

Comment: What output you expect for n=4? (Not sure which definition you have for faces/sides for higher dimensions).

Comment: @Stef I know the coordinates of the vertices and that's it, I guess.

Comment: @trincot For n=4, I want 48 3D sides (rectangles).

Comment: Doable with the computation of the convex hull, but I don't know whether there is an appropriate library in JavaScript.

Comment: Found the same question and an answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71256623/algorithm-to-dynamically-generate-m-face-list-for-n-dimensional-hypercube