# GLM: How to create a matrix of 9 columns and 3 rows

Tags: c++, matrix, glm-math

I know only one way which is `glm::mat4 matrix`

I tried even `float matrix[9][3]` which didn't work, I need it to multiply it with `glm::vec3`

How to create?

Comment: i'm afraid that would be beyond glm library capabilities since it is not some sort of generic math library

Comment: A matrix with 9 columns can't be multiplied to a vec3 since the inner dimensions of the multiplication doesn't match. At least not with the OpenGL Notation where vectors are column vectors. Are you sure you're not looking for a Matrix with 9 rows? But then the result would be a 9d-vector which wouldn't have any meaning in OpenGL.

Comment: You could `typedef glm::mat<9, 3, float, glm::defaultp> mat9x3`, but this really smells like an XY-problem. What would you do with the resulting `glm::mat<9,1,...>` ?

Comment: @Botje The 9d vector is storing x,y,z angles of 3 joints

Comment: @BDL Yeah, I'm sorry! I'm going to take transpose of it then multiply with vec3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compute that with 3x3 sub matrices and combine the outputs into final result. There are two options:

1. **9 rows**

   ```
    a a a       u'
    a a a       u'
    a a a       u'
    b b b   u   v'
    b b b * u = v'
    b b b   u   v'
    c c c       w'
    c c c       w'
    c c c       w'
   ```

   this is really simple:

   ```
    u' = a*u
    v' = b*u
    w' = c*u
   ```
2. **9 columns**

   ```
                        u
                        u
                        u
    a a a b b b c c c   v   u' 
    a a a b b b c c c * v = u'
    a a a b b b c c c   v   u'
                        w
                        w
                        w
   ```

This is more complicated but not by much:

```
    u.x' = (a*u).x + (b*v).x + (c*w).x
    u.y' = (a*u).y + (b*v).y + (c*w).y
    u.z' = (a*u).z + (b*v).z + (c*w).z
```

This is common way for expanding dimensionality in GLSL for example for purposes like these:

- [4D rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44970550/2521214)
- [4D rotations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45116079/2521214)

**[Edit1] 9x3 and 3x9 matrices version:**

```
+-----+                         +-----------------+
|     |                         |     |     |     |
|  A  |                         | A*U | A*V | A*W |
|     |                         |     |     |     |
|-----|   +-----------------+   |-----+-----+-----|
|     |   |     |     |     |   |     |     |     |
|  B  | * |  U  |  V  |  W  | = | B*U | B*V | B*W |
|     |   |     |     |     |   |     |     |     |
|-----|   +-----------------+   |-----+-----+-----|
|     |                         |     |     |     |
|  C  |                         | C*U | C*V | C*W |
|     |                         |     |     |     |
+-----+                         +-----------------+

                               +--------+
                               |u1 u2 u3|
                               |u1 u2 u3|
                               |u1 u2 u3|
+--------------------------+   |--------|   +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|a1 a1 a1|b1 b1 b1|c1 c1 c1|   |v1 v2 v3|   | (a1.u1)+(b1.v1)+(c1.w1) | (a1.u2)+(b1.v2)+(c1.w2) | (a1.u3)+(b1.v3)+(c1.w3) |
|a2 a2 a2|b2 b2 b2|c2 c2 c2| * |v1 v2 v3| = | (a2.u1)+(b2.v1)+(c2.w1) | (a2.u2)+(b2.v2)+(c2.w2) | (a2.u3)+(b2.v3)+(c2.w3) |
|a3 a3 a3|b3 b3 b3|c3 c3 c3|   |v1 v2 v3|   | (a3.u1)+(b3.v1)+(c3.w1) | (a3.u2)+(b3.v2)+(c3.w2) | (a3.u3)+(b3.v3)+(c3.w3) |
+--------------------------+   |--------|   +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                               |w1 w2 w3|
                               |w1 w2 w3|
                               |w1 w2 w3|
                               +--------+
```

where `(a1.u1)` means dot product between `(a1,a1,a1)` and `(u1,u1,u1)` and uppercase `A` means entire `3x3` submatrix

Comment: How would you do this for multiplying the 9x3 matrix by its transpose to result in a 3x3 matrix? If it's split into 3 different matrixes does that help or hurt your ability to do this multiplication?

Comment: @Ethan I added edit1 hope I did not make any mistake (still did not have my morning tea ...) your case is the second example ...