# How to represent a rotation/orientation in N dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy, data-structures, rotation

I'm trying to represent coordinate systems (and transformations between them) in arbitrary dimensions. A coordinate system can be described by its pose (position + orientation) and I am unsure how to best represent its orientation in arbitrary dimensions.

Based on my search, it should be possible to represent an arbitrary pose as a sequence of rotations ([source](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/371892/rotation-in-higher-dimensions)). Further, it should be possible to represent an arbitrary rotation by an angle (amount to rotate), and a plane in which to rotate ([source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197772/generalized-rotation-matrix-in-n-dimensional-space-around-n-2-unit-vector)). This means I should be able to do something like this in code

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List
from numpy.typing import ArrayLike


@dataclass
class Rotation:
    # amount to rotate
    alpha: float
    # two vectors spanning the plane
    u: ArrayLike
    v: ArrayLike

@dataclass
class Orientation:
    orientation: List[Rotation]
```

This seems quite naive and inefficient. Each rotation has to be applied one at a time, which may not be very efficient computationally speaking. It is also non-unique. For example, these three objects represent the same orientation

```py
Orientation(Rotation(np.pi, (0, 1), (1, 0)))
Orientation(Rotation(-np.pi, (1, 0), (0, 1)))
Orientation([Rotation(np.pi, (0, 1), (1, 0)), Rotation(0.42, (0, 1), (1, 0)), Rotation(-0.42, (0, 1), (1, 0))])
```

How can I improve this and what is the best data structure to use here?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45116079/2521214 for ND use (N+1) x (N+1)  [homogenuous transform matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214).

Answer (score 2):

[Rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) can represent rotations in arbitrary N dimensions.

It is possible to compose rotation matrices using the matrix product. So you'd need only to store a single matrix to represent an orientation, even if it's constructed from multiple individual rotations.

While a single plane/angle representation is more memory efficient than a full matrix, one matrix can represent the combination of multiple plane/angle rotations.
Also, applying a matrix transformation is very efficient - just a couple of dot products.

In 3D space it's often beneficial to represent rotations as [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)<s>, but I don't think they can be generalized to arbitrary dimensionality</s>. Although they can be generalized to ND space, this is is not very intuitive<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Thank you, [Spektre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2521214/spektre), for the clarifying [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67599577/how-to-represent-a-rotation-orientation-in-n-dimensions/67600487?noredirect=1#comment120095921_67600487).</sub>

Comment: Quaternions will indeed not work well in spaces other than 3D. In 4D you need a pair of two quaternions to uniquely represent a rotation. This (ofc) doesn't hold in 6D and so forth. The math on how to do this properly exists (some buzzwords are Clifford-Algebra, Rotors, k-vectors), but I am not well-versed enough in geometric algebra to work it out myself x)

Comment: [quaternions generalized to ND are possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49031090/2521214) however not intuitive just like in 3D ... transform matrices are way better ...